# Draco javascript decodere lose uv coordinates

Tags: three.js

I have a working three.js app that works fine with object models. My models are quite big, and take some times to load, so I decided to try [draco](https://github.com/google/draco) to compress them.

I have notice that draco terminal tools work correct. When I encode/decode the obj model "manually" in termina and then use it in may old project, it works as expected. The model size is a little bit smaller then before, due to some looses draco introduce, but it still looks fine. 
However when I try do compress the models and use them in my three.js app I get a high level of compression but I lose my uv coordinates. I am not sure if uv loosing is caused by some bug in javascript draco_decoder or I miss some step when creating a mesh from buffer geometry.

I know that compressed and decompressed model work fine because I can see it in my browser textures and aoMap work perfectly. I also pretty sure that uv and uv1 are gone when I try to use drc model directly becouse I can't see the coordinates in geometry.buffer_geometry.attributes of my mesh.

to make things clear I incorporate the functions I use to create mesh  below

//this one prepare http request for draco file and pass it to decode function

```
function loadCompressedModel( model , onEnd, onLoading ){
    draco_file = new XMLHttpRequest();
    draco_file.open("GET", model , true);
    draco_file.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    draco_file.send();

    interval = window.setInterval(
        onLoading,
        500
    );

    draco_file.onload = function(e) {
        window.clearInterval( interval );
        decompresDracoModel(
            draco_file.response,
            onEnd

        );
        console.log("download is complite");
    };

    return draco_file;
}
```

//this create mesh from bufferGeometry, onEnd do not touch the geometry only the material of the mesh

```
function decompresDracoModel( raw_data , onEnd ){
//DracoModuel and display area are declared globaly
    var bufferGeometry = dracoLoader.decodeDracoFile( raw_data );

    var mesh;
    var group = new THREE.Group();

    bufferGeometry.computeVertexNormals();
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( bufferGeometry, material );
    bufferGeometry.computeBoundingBox();

    group.add( mesh );

    onEnd( group );
}
```

Comment: I have forgot, my model use one .mtl, i am sure that this is the problem. But I still get trouble to understand how to solve it.